# Customer registration with customer group

Tags: customer

I want to add customer group dropdown option to customer registration

I had added below observer code for it. I added dropdown of all customer group in registration form with name (for example `cgroupuser`), but my code is not working:

```
class Customere_Group_Model_Observer
{
    public function customerRegisterSuccess(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {       
        try {

            $customer = $observer->getEvent()->getCustomer();
            $customer->setData('group_id', $_POST['cgroupuser']); // or whatever the group id should be
            $customer->save();

        } catch ( Exception $e ) {}
    }
}
```

What am I missing? If I put static val `$_POST['cgroupuser']` it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

sauravm,Plese use `Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('cgroupuser')` instead of `$_POST['cgroupuser']`